# Use MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE with node.js?

Tags: mysql, database, node.js, bulk-load

Are there any node.js MySQL drivers that support LOAD DATA INFILE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)? I have some utilities that rely heavily on bulk insertion, and can't find any node.js drivers that explicitly mention supporting it.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/22ed873f1303605b?pli=1) suggests that the [felixge](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) driver supports LOAD DATA INFILE.

Answer (score 1):

Just verified that it works:

```
conn.query('LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ? INTO TABLE my_table (col1, col2)', 
  [pathToFile], 
  function(err) {
    //done
  });
```

Comment: It works for me as above using the NPM mysql library - not the mysql2 (bummer).